# C programming, making a loop from code that is repetitive

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Is there any chance to make a loop for this repetitive code, so it executes for let's say n times?

The task is to always enter a new element in the first place of array, moving existing elements to the right. Iguess there are more ways to do it but I just need to know if it's possible to set this code in a loop. BTW: I used `#define` to make

```
#define SWAP(x,y) t=x;x=y;y=t;
```

Fragment to convert to loop:

```
printf("enter next member of array");
SWAP(*(p + 0), *(p + 1))
    scanf("%d", p);

printf("enter next member of array");
SWAP(*(p + 1), *(p + 2))
SWAP(*(p + 0), *(p + 1))
    scanf("%d", p);

printf("enter next member of array");
SWAP(*(p + 2), *(p + 3))
SWAP(*(p + 1), *(p + 2))
SWAP(*(p + 0), *(p + 1))
    scanf("%d", p);

printf("enter next member of array");
SWAP(*(p + 3), *(p + 4))
SWAP(*(p + 2), *(p + 3))
SWAP(*(p + 1), *(p + 2))
SWAP(*(p + 0), *(p + 1))
    scanf("%d", p);
```

Comment: "is there any chance to make a loop for this repetitive code?" Yes. Repetitive code can always be converted into a loop. I suggest going a step further and create a `insert()` or `push()` function.

Comment: Perhaps [`memmove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k35d1fx.aspx) can help you.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Your question doesn't quite fit the format that is expected here, I think. In particular, the idea of SO is not to write the code for you.

Comment: Why not insert all the elements... and then reverse the array? So you'll do a linear amount of swaps instead of a quadratic amount...

Comment: @JensGustedt I understand all criticism, but this is my first post on stack overflow, i will try to do better next time.
Storyteller, thats not so hard, the thing is to always insert new element on the first place of the array, moving other element to the right

Comment: One option is to read the data into the array in reverse order (so the first one goes in index 0, the second in index 1, etc) and then reverse the populated part of the array after the loop.  It means your values will move less often.  Also, using `p[0]` instead of `*(p + 0)` is sensible; the pointer notation has no benefit other than being harder to type so that it improves your typing skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    printf("enter next member of array");
    for ( int j = i; j >= 0; --j ) {
        SWAP(*(p + j), *(p + j + 1))
    }
    scanf("%d", p);
}
```

Note: I haven't tried it, but that should be enough for you to figure out the rest. Note, however, that there are much more efficient ways to do what you want. But I'm answering your original question.

Comment: thank you very much, it works, i know that there are more efficient ways to finish the task, but i was really curious about this way

Comment: @DaniloGacevic Up-vote and mark as official answer then? Thanks.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Just did.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a `push()` function. Take a look at the examples you gave in your code and look for the patterns that can help you turn the repetition into a loop. You first need a counter, say `i`, that goes from `0` to some number. How do you determine what the maximum number is? Then you need to use `i` to calculate the expression in each swap. Look at the pattern in your current code to get some ideas how to write a single line of code inside your for loop.